# Update column year based on another column year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update year and month from a datetime column reflecting year and month of another `DateTime` column from a different table. see example below.

```sql
update table1
set datepart(year(Month(date1)) = datepart(year(Month(date2)) -- inaccurate method just for example
from table1
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
where year(date1) <> year(date2)
```

Current data

```
table1 
ID    |  Date1 
User1  1/26/2021
User2   2/27/2018
User3   3/26/2023


table2
ID    |  Date1
User1   2/2/2022
User2   3/1/2021
User3   6/3/2022

Result

table1 
ID    |  Date1 
User1   2/26/2022
User2   3/27/2021
User3   6/26/2022
```

There are different years and months in date1 and the plan is to update all years and months to match the date2 column from table2.

Comment: Try [datefromparts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or simply add the difference in years using datediff / dateadd. Think carefully about leap year and how February end-of-month values should be handled.

Comment: there is different years and all need to match the year in date2

Comment: Just curios: how do you want to treat leap years?

Comment: `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` would seem the "best" solution here, as @SMor suggested. That won't have issues with things like leap years (that `DATEFROMPARTS` would).

Comment: It could be any year from date1 the plan is to match the year in date2.

Comment: So are you saying `DATEDIFF` and `DATEADD` won't work? Why not? I don't understand what you're trying to tell us in your comments that you don't already in your question.

Comment: And here's what everyone is talking about when they mean you need to decide how to handle leap years. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5efe6e84fbefea3574c6f4bf3cd53309

Comment: I updated my post. there is no a fix date I'm looking to update to. the plan is to look at the records in date2 and update date1 based on values in date2.

Comment: for the leap year, I haven't thought of that, so thanks for bringing up, and any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Your result shows 2 out of 3 with invalid dates.  You need to define the rules to avoid invalid dates based on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your date column to varchar since  the data '2018/02/30' does not exist.

```
 declare @a TABLE (
   ID    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Date1 varchar(30)  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @a(ID,Date1) VALUES ('User1','1/31/2021');
INSERT INTO @a(ID,Date1) VALUES ('User2','2/30/2018');
INSERT INTO @a(ID,Date1) VALUES ('User3','3/31/2023');
declare @b TABLE (
   ID    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,Date1 varchar(30)  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @b(ID,Date1) VALUES ('User1','2/2/2022');
INSERT INTO @b(ID,Date1) VALUES ('User2','3/1/2021');
INSERT INTO @b(ID,Date1) VALUES ('User3','6/3/2022');
```

update statement

```
update @a  set 
date1=cast(concat(
PARSENAME(REPLACE(b.Date1,'/','.'),3),'/',
PARSENAME(REPLACE(a.Date1,'/','.'),2),'/',
PARSENAME(REPLACE(b.Date1,'/','.'),1)) as date) 
FROM @a a join @b b
on a.ID=b.ID
```

you can use the following query if your data was correct

```
update @a 
set Date1=
cast(concat(Year(b.Date1),'/',Day(a.Date1),'/',Month(b.Date1)) as date)
FROM @a a join @b b
on a.ID=b.ID
```

Comment: My bad, the date was just an example and I used the wrong date.

Comment: Did this query worked? or it requires modifications